# How to close a stream created with GdipCreateStreamOnFile

Tags: gdi+, filestream

The GDI+ flat interface (gdiplusflat.h) declares a function
GdipCreateStreamOnFile

How is that stream supposed to be closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `pStream->Release()`.

Comment: Yes it does. If you want to close the file, you release the stream.